# Can't read Arabic text file in Java

Tags: java, file, text

i am trying to read arabic text using Java , yet the scanner does not see any elements and thus reading is unsuccessful although LineNumberReader recognizes lines in the text file.

i have tried the same code on English text and it works fine.

i am using netbeans 7.0.1

here is my code :

```
public class ReadFile {
    private int number_of_words;
    private File f1;
    private String array[][],lines[];
    private Scanner scan1;

    public ReadFile(String sf1) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        f1=new File(sf1);
        scan1=new Scanner(f1);

    }

    public String[][] getA()
    {
        return array;
    }

    public void read() throws IOException
    {
        int counter=0,i=0;

        LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f1));
        lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        number_of_words=lnr.getLineNumber();
        array = new String[2][number_of_words];
        lines = new String[number_of_words];
        while(scan1.hasNext())
      {
        String temp;
        temp=scan1.nextLine();
        lines[counter++] = temp;
                        System.out.println(lines[counter-1]+"\t"+lines.length);

      }

       Arrays.sort(lines);
       counter=0;

       while(i<lines.length)
       {
           String temp = lines[i++];
           StringTokenizer tk=new StringTokenizer(temp,"\t");

           array[0][counter] = tk.nextToken();
           array[1][counter++] = tk.nextToken();
       }
     }
 }
```

Comment: NetBeans is irrelevant here so I'm removing that tag.  Also, accept more answers - your rate is rather low.

Answer (score 3):

By default scanner uses system encoding. You need to use correct character encoding while reading data special characters.

```
scan1=new Scanner(f1, "UTF-8");
```

If UTF-8 didn't work you need to try with arabic specific encoding.

Here are couple of links may be useful [File reading practices](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42) and [Java supported encodings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the file with this:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f1);
LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8"));
```

You need to use the right [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) when reading the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably what you are looking for:

```
Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8")
```